# Ray performance decrease when increase the number of workers in a three node cluster

Tags: ray

#### System information

- **OS Platform and Distribution (Linux redhat 7.6)**:
- **Ray installed using pip install -U ray **:
- **Ray version**:0.8.0
- **Python version**:3.7

#### Describe the problem

I have setup a three node manual cluster setup , and ran a sample ppo trainer using rllib, as part of my test , I tested for 40 iteration and 240 iteration(refer the for loop in the code) and  each run i change the workers (config["num_workers"] ) from  1, 4, 8, 16, 24, 32 and The execution time decreases initially for 1,4,8,16 as expected but started increasing for 24, 32. since my cluster has 64 cores(i can see total 64 workers available in the machines (16+16+32), my expectation is when i increase the workers threads , it should reduce the execution time which happens upto 16 workers then started increasing any idea on this?

#### Result from my test

- 40 Iteration
  -- 1 worker - 5.9 min, 4 workers - 3.4 mins, 8 workers -3.1 mins, 16 workers-2.9 mins, 24 workers-3.2 mins, 32 workers -4.3 mins
- 240 Iteration
  -- 1 worker - 35.6 min, 4 workers - 20.4 mins, 8 workers -18.2 mins, 16 workers-17.6 mins, 24 workers-19.5 mins, 32 workers -25.2 mins

#### Cluster details

- Head Node - Redhat linux 7.6 with 16 cores only cpu, 64GB memory
- Worker Node1 - Redhat linux 7.6 with 16 cores only cpu, 64 GB memory
- Worker Node2 - Redhat linux 7.6 with 32 cores, 128 GB memory

#### Code

```
import ray 
import ray.rllib.agents.ppo as ppo  
from ray.tune.logger import pretty_print 
import time  

ray.init(redis_address="HEADNODEIP:6379",redis_password="REDIS_PASSWORD") 
config = ppo.DEFAULT_CONFIG.copy() 
config["num_gpus"] = 0
config["num_workers"] = 16
config["eager"] = False
trainer = ppo.PPOTrainer(config=config, env="CartPole-v0")
start = time.time()

for i in range(40):
   # Perform one iteration of training the policy with PPO
   result = trainer.train()
   trainer.workers.foreach_worker(lambda ev: print(ev.get_policy().get_weights()))
   #print(pretty_print(result))

   if i % 10 == 0:
       checkpoint = trainer.save()
   print("checkpoint saved at", checkpoint)

print('Total time to process in seconds : ', time.time() - start)
```